# 'Build' function included in html5 boilerplate

Tags: php, javascript, css, optimization, html

This may be a stupid question but how does one actually run the 'Build' functions of the new html5 boilerplate package?

I believe it must have to be run from some kind of command line interface as all Paul Irish states in the documentation is simply:

navigate into the build folder:

```
cd build
```

build your site:

```
ant build
```

Full documentation on the Build-Script is here:
https://github.com/paulirish/html5-boilerplate/wiki/Build-script

I am only familiar with the windows GUI view and not the CMD Line interface. I'm sure this is very obvious to programmers more experienced than myself. Would just love to get access to some of these great site optimisation features in the latest version of HTML5 Boilerplate!

Thanks guys,

W.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need *ant*, which is a build tool for Java application development. You can download it here: http://ant.apache.org/

Secondly, you did not mention what operating you are using; so I assume you are using Windows. The command line interface you need is the command promt. You can get that by going to the start menu, execute command and enter "cmd". After that a black window should appear.

Check *ant*'s documentation on how to install it on your computer. If you do it right, you will be able to enter `ant build` into the command line and it should do what you expect from the boilerplate documentation.

Comment: So what is a compiler? Could you spell out what exactly he means in his documentation, would really appreciate it :)

Comment: Sorry. Forget what I said. I'll update my answer in a moment.

Comment: Thx badcat and wilson, I've updated the docs pages with the extra detail here: https://github.com/paulirish/html5-boilerplate/wiki/Build-script

Comment: there is actually a batch file (.bat) for inside the build/ folder that Windows users can just double click to run the build process. no need to open up the command prompt. you'll still need ant, though, for the batch file to work

Answer (score 0):

Thanks badcat!

I ended up using [WinAnt](http://code.google.com/p/winant/) to install Apache Ant as it seemed mega complicated without. This then prompted me to install the Java JDK and gave me a link to do so. Did all that and then accessed the build file using command prompt like badcat said and hey presto one nice compacted/optimised site!

Thanks a bunch mate!

W.